TruClient Left and Right function
I am using LoadRunner TruClient. The object is a table. I have the JavaScript picking a random number and going to that row. In that row, it saves the value in column 0 to a parameter and column 1 to a different parameter. My issue is that when it saves column 0, it is grabbing the HTML tags too. Example: < b>000123123< /b>
I need to remove the HTML bold tag to save it as a parameter, but everything I've tried hasn't worked.
var RanRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) +1);
TC.setParam('serv_dlr', object.rows[RanRow].cells[0].innerHTML);
TC.setParam('call_nbr', object.rows[RanRow].cells[1].innerHTML);

Table
Expressions and Values
I tried using variations of this:
var RanRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) +1);
var ServicingDealer = object.rows[RanRow].cells[0].innerHTML;
var ServicingDealer2 = ServicingDealer.left(12);
var ServicingDealer3 = ServicingDealer.right(9);
TC.setParam('serv_dlr', ServicingDealer3);

Results
